# Remove elements from a hash array if a value matches a line in a text file

Tags: ruby

I have a JSON file with a hash in that looks like this

```
{
  "1": {
    "organisation": "Example1",
    "name": "Name1",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Name1",
        "html_url": "URL1",
        "results": [
          "items go here"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Name2",
        "html_url": "URL2",
        "results": [
          "Items go here"
        ]
      },
```

I want to delete elements whose html_url matches a list stored in a text file, I have been toying with a delete-if like this.

```
@org.each do |key,value|
    File.open('views/investigated.txt').each do |line|
        value['items'].delete_if { |h| h['html_url'] == line }                
    end
end
```

but it doesn't seem to alter the array, I'm completely lost, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `each` returns the whole line, including the newline character. You probably have to `chomp` it. BTW, traversing the whole file for each pair in `@org` might not be the best idea ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stefan is right, it's better practice to create a separate array with the lines you'd like to delete from the array:

```
urls_to_delete = []
File.open('views/investigated.txt').each do |line|
    urls_to_delete.push(line)
end
```

Then use that array to remove the lines from the hash:

```
@org.each do |key,value|
    value['items'].delete_if { |h| urls_to_delete.include?(h['html_url']) }
end
```

Tested it with your example and does exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps `urls_to_delete = File.readlines('views/investigated.txt').map(&:chomp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can delete records in one iteration by using `each_key` on ˙@org˙ and you dont need new array.
Like this:

```
@org.each_key do |key|
  File.open('views/investigated.txt').each do |line|
    line.chomp!
    @org[key]['items'].delete_if { |h| h['html_url'] == line }
  end
end
```

Comment: If the file `"views/investigated.txt"` is extremely large I can see why you might not want to (or be able to) read it into an array.  In that case, you might first compile a list of the elements `@org[key]['items']` and then match each line of the file against the elements of that list. Instead, you are proposing to step through each line of the file for each value `@org[key]['items']`. That strikes me as hugely inefficient.